# Как получить значение функции, вызываемой через tkinter.Button и записать ее в новую переменную? (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter, область-видимости

Есть кнопка "загрузить токены",

```
load_tokens_btn = tk.Button(text="Загрузить файл с txt токенами", command=open_tokens)
```

при нажатии на которую вызывается функция open_tokens()

```
def open_tokens():
    op = fd.askopenfilename()
    file = fileinput.input(op)
    tokens = [x for x in file]
    return tokens
```

и появляется диалоговое окно для открытия файла.[image: диалоговое окно]

юзер выбирает txt файл, этот txt файл читается и записывается в список tokens внутри функции open_tokens().
Сам вопрос - как "достать" этот список tokens из функции open_tokens() и засунуть этот список tokens в "глобальный код"? Потому что мне нужно в дальнейшем работать со списком tokens.

return tokens не работает, да и возвращать ему значение некуда.

Comment: - "return tokens не работает"
- Что значит *не работает*?! 
- "возвращать ему значение некуда" 
- Как это *некуда*?!  У Вас же есть место в программе, где этот список токенов используется, почему нельзя просто написать *token_list = open_tokens()* ?

Answer (score 1):

Создать массив вне функции (после импорта), и в функции просто изменять эту переменную:

```
tokens = []
# остальной код
def open_tokens():
    global tokens # чтобы не создать новую локальную переменную в следующей строчке
    tokens = [x for x in file]
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть 2 пути

1. Создать класс, в него запихнуть само окно и функцию открытия окна. Далее через `self.tokens` сделать переменную для чтения её из класса и можно дальше, внутри класса или извне обращаться к ней также(извне `self` меняем на переменную, которая является экземпляром класса)
2. Просто создать `tokens` как глобальную переменную